# try to send an array of objects that has another array of objects from vu to laravel controller

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, axios, vue-component

Im trying to create a test, each test has an image(file) and one or more questions, and each question has an (file) and one or more choices...

1. each questions has questions_text and questions_file and questions_choices(array of objects)
   **this is my data() function:**

```js
data(){

        return{
            succees:false,
            numberQuestions:null,
            file:null,
            questions_counter:1,
            categories:[],
            form: new Form({
                test_type:'1',
                test_name:'',
                test_description:'',
                test_duration:null,
                test_image,
                questions:[
                    {
                        q_text:null,
                        q_file:null,
                        choices:[
                            {choice_text:null,correct_choice:false}
                        ],
                        numberChoices:null,
                    },
                ],
            })
        }
    },
```

**And this is my submit fucntions:**

```js
methods:{

        sumbitTest(){
            axios({
                url: '/submit-test',
                data: {
                    test_name:this.form.test_name,
                    test_type:this.form.test_type,
                    test_description:this.form.test_description,
                    test_duration:this.form.test_duration,
                    test_image:this.form.test_image,
                    questions:this.form.questions
                },
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'content-type':'multipart/form-data'}
            })
            .then((response)=>{
                if(response.status === 200){
                    this.succees = true;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => this.form.errors.record(error.response.data));
        },
```

And this is my controller `functions submitTest()`:

```php
public function submitTest(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'test_name' => '',
            'test_type' => '',
            'test_description' => '',
            'test_duration' => '',
            'questions' => ''
        ]);
        dd($request->questions);
        $test = new Test();
        $test->test_name = $request->test_name;
        $test->description = $request->test_description;
        $test->duration = $request->test_duration;
        $test->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $test->category_id = $request->test_type;
        $test->test_image = $request->test_image;
        $test->save();
        foreach($request->questions as $question){
            $Question = new Question();
            $Question->question_text = $question['q_text'];
            $Question->question_file = $question['q_file'];
            $Question->test_id = $test->id;
            $Question->save();
            foreach($question['choices'] as $choice){
                $Choice = new Choice();
                $Choice->c_text = $choice['choice_text'];
                $Choice->correct_choice = $choice['correct_choice'];
                $Choice->question_id = $Question->id;
                $Choice->save();
            }
        }

        return response()->json(['success']);
    }
```

I did Console.log() for all the data [questions,test_name,...] and its working fine in vue side, but Im getting null when I dd($request); in laravel side, What is the right way to send an array of objects that has files and also has another array of objects ?
Thanks you so much for help ^-^

Comment: Hello Mohamed Annajar, Welcome to Stackoverflow.
I think we with a bit more of info we can help, Can you show your controller?

Comment: HI thank u for your answer, I updated my post and I added the submit function that responsable for adding a new test with questions.., but I really think the main problem is in my fronend side [sumbitTest() method in my vue conponent].

Comment: Okay , I can see, 2 things, Can you see the data that is being send to server in the request?.  I see you´re trying to ``dd($request->questions)``, just to be sure ``dd($request->all())`` is displaying anything?

Comment: there is 2 things: (1) when I send the data without headers: {'content-type':'multipart/form-data'} it shows me all the data like normal and my test_image and all questions_files are null, (2) when I send the data with headers: {'content-type':'multipart/form-data'} I get NULL (no data sended) when I dd($request->all()); And I think I really need to add headers: {'content-type':'multipart/form-data'} because Im sending files too..

Comment: If you want to update files, you definitely add the header ``'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'``, I think the problem could be in  the array of files, What is the HTML for that? Do you give them any especial treatment?

Comment: I found a new solution and its really working, I tried to append the questions array in a defrent way:   for (let i = 0; i < this.form.questions.length; i++) {
                for (let key of Object.keys(this.form.questions[i])) {
                    data.append(`questions[${i}][${key}]`, this.form.questions[i][key]);
                }
            } everything is fine when I dd($request), BUT The onley problem problem is that I'm getting the choices array as undefind like this [object,object] in my controller, any idea how to make this work ? Im really thankfull ^-^

Comment: Glad you solve you current situation, I recommend to create an other question, since the current issue you have is addressed to other matter. Regards.